# Captain America aging question

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

How can Captain America become old in Endgame when he is injected with soldier serum ?

Comment: That other question is not a duplicate because its talking about timeline inconsistencies regarding cap. This question simply asks about Caps Aging rate. As a super soldier he ages really slow, say half the human rate. Assuming he's a 100 years in the last scene, one might have expected him to look say .. 50. He looks a lot older.

Comment: MovieMe is correct about this not being a duplicate of the question linked by @Paulie_D. It should be reopened.

Comment: There's no indication that the Super Soldier serum slows aging. If you have an MCU source for this please provide it.

Comment: While that may be a possible answer, the question still remains non-duplicate.